# Where to put "Non-Authorization" Access Control Logic, Doesn't seem to fit into ACL?

Tags: zend-framework, acl, web-applications

I am wondering for "Non-Authorization" Access Control Logic eg. One can only add children todos on top level todos. It doesn't seem to fit into ACL's where it seem to be more for Authentication/Authorization Access Control Logic?

Do I put all into my ACL? I must somehow show different error messages tho, eg. 'You cannot perform this action' instead of 'You don't have sufficient permissions to perform this action' ... how might I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle the access logic outside your access list object. I created a frontController plugin for this purpose:

```
class Soflomo_Controller_Plugin_Access extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function dispatchLoopStartup (Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        if (!$this->_isAllowed($request)) {
            throw new Zend_Controller_Action_Exception('No permission', 403);
        }
    }

    protected function _isAllowed (Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request, $permission = 'view')
    {
        $acl = new Acl(); // Here your logic to fetch a (cached) ACL
        $role = new User(); // Here your logic to fetch role
        $resource = new Page(); // Here your logic to fetch resource

        return $acl->hasRole($role)
            && $acl->has($resource)
            && $acl->isAllowed($role, $resource, $permission);
    }
}
```

In this case, I explicitly check the existence of a role and resource. This is because I have only the ACL rules in my database where the role has access to the resource. All other cases (when user does not have the access) I leave it out of the database.

When you have a different logic, it is perhaps enough to check for `$acl->isAllowed($role, $resource, $permission);` and leave the `$acl->hasRole()` and `$acl->has()` out.

**Error handler**

I throw a Zend_Controller_Action_Exception with error code 403, but if you don't catch the specific code, it will look like a normal application error. Therefore I added in the ErrorHandler frontController plugin another constant `EXCEPTION_NO_PERMISSION` and added this to the switch statement:

```
case 'Zend_Controller_Action_Exception':
if (404 == $exception->getCode()) {
    $error->type = self::EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION;
} elseif (403 == $exception->getCode()) {
    $error->type = self::EXCEPTION_NO_PERMISSION;
} else {
    $error->type = self::EXCEPTION_OTHER;
}
break;
```

Then you can fetch the error type `EXCEPTION_NO_PERMISSION` in your ErrorController.

Comment: aren't you using `Zend_Acl` still? but u said "You should handle the access logic outside your access list object, when you say access list object u mean `Zend_Acl`?

Comment: I mean `Zend_Acl` is the list, so it is the data object with all the roles, resources and permissions. If you try to apply some logic (a logged in user performs a certain request, should we allow this?) isn't the place for `Zend_Acl` since it's only the list providing the data. That is what I call "access logic" and should be handled in a frontController plugin, action helper or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way is to handle the logic in the controller plugin. This works well in most cases,
but I'd recommend to store the logic in your models.

ACL is a model too.

Any model/form/class may implement `Zend_Acl_Resource_Interface` just by providing `getResourceId()` method:
e.g.

```
abstract class My_Form_Acl extends Zend_Form {

    public function __construct() {
       // ...
       parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getResourceId()
    {
       return get_class($this);
    }
}
```